# Removing pandas rows based on existence of values in certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like so:

```
A B C
f s x
a b c
n
p l k
i
s j p
```

Now, I want to remove all the records that have the value in column A but are empty on the rest of df's columns, how can I achieve such a thing? The expected result would be a df like:

```
A B C
f s x
a b c
p l k
s j p
```

@EDIT:
this solved the case for me:

```
columns = list(df.columns)[1:]
df = df[~df[columns].isnull().all(1)]
```

Comment: would it be possible to be empty in A and not in B/C, would you want to keep the row in this case?

Comment: @mozway hard to tell, I don't know what to expect from this data set. I guess it won't be the case.

Comment: In any case, I provided alternatives for both cases. The advantage of boolean indexing is that it's quite flexible to combine conditions (A AND B, A OR B, A XOR B…) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) in order to set blanks to NaN, then you can remove rows with NaN with [`DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).dropna()
```

Or if you want remove only if column A is not NaN

```
df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
  .loc[lambda x: ~(x['A'].notna() 
                   & x.filter(regex='!A').isna().all(axis=1))]
#morgan equivalent
#df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
#  .loc[lambda x: x['A'].isna() 
#                 | x.filter(regex='!A').notna().any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: the thing is I can have a value in column A and C and not in B and dropna will remove such a row. I want to remove the row only when there is a value in A and the rest of the records are empty

Comment: thanks @JakubSapko , I have edited my answer, you could use `.loc` option

Comment: well, by using your second code I got an empty df xD

Answer (score 0):

If you have empty (NaN) cells in B/C a simple `dropna` will work:

```
df.dropna()
```

Else, use boolean indexing:

```
df[df.ne('').all(1)]
```

output:

```
   A  B  C
0  f  s  x
1  a  b  c
3  p  l  k
5  s  j  p
```

**Note**

Although I doubt you would want this, if you want to drop the rows only when A is not `''`, add a second condition:

```
df[df['A'].eq('')|df.ne('').all(1)]
```

example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x',  '',  '', 'x', '', 'x'],
                   'B': ['x', 'x',  '', 'x', '', ''],
                   'C': ['x', 'x', 'x',  '', '', '']})
   A  B  C
0  x  x  x
1     x  x
2        x
3  x  x   
4         
5  x
```

output:

```
   A  B  C
0  x  x  x
1     x  x
2        x
4
```

Comment: the thing is I can have a value in column A and C and not in B and dropna will remove such a row. I want to remove the row only when there is a value in A and the rest of the records are empty

Comment: Then `df[df['A'].eq('')|df.ne('').all(1)]` will work like that

Comment: check my less ambiguous example and let me know which rows you would keep/delete

Comment: So I would expect row 5 to be dropped. I checked the data and there won't be such a thing like a row 1, 2 or 4

Comment: OK, then you need `df[df.drop(columns='A').ne('').any(1)]`, which is "*keep the row if any value is not `''` among all columns but A*".

Comment: For some reason it doesn't seem to be affecting the df at all

Comment: Well, you must assign the output!  `new_df = df[df.drop(columns='A').ne('').any(1)]`

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of that. Is this ok to use '' in ne rather than for example numpy.nan?

Comment: @Jakub it depends on what you have in your real data, is NaN use `isna`/`notna`, if `''`, use `eq('')`/`ne('')` or replace the `''` with `pd.NA` first